# Почему std::get_if принимает std::variant по указателю?

Tags: c++, c++17, union

Почему `std::get_if` принимает `std::variant` по указателю, а не по ссылке, как `std::get`?

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества что именно непонятно?

Comment: В современном C++ стараются избавляться от голых указателей, а тут он есть, хотя в соседнем методе нет. Почему?

Comment: у указателя есть возможность иметь значение **nullptr**, может по-этому ..

Comment: Вероятно, потому что понадобился *non-throwing accessor* — а это можно обеспечить при указателе, а вот при ссылке очень проблематично. Вспомните `dynamic_cast`, например...